# Sending formulas with Google Forms

Tags: google-sheets, google-forms

I'm trying to give a formula using the equal sign, when submitting a Short answer in a Google Form. If I'm writing

```
=6+3
```

into the form and then submit it, I get the string

```
'=6+3
```

in the Google Sheet Response sheet. It does not seem to calculate this function automatically.

When trying to `getValue()` this cell, I cannot find the quote, and so I cannot execute this function.

Does anyone have any good idea to solve this problem? Is it possible to execute this function in the Response sheet?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following function gets the active range value and set it as the active cell formula:

```
function stringToFormula() {
  var rng = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveRange();
  var value = rng.getValue();
  rng.setFormula(value);
}
```

If the cell value is `'=6+7` the cell formula will be `=6+7` and the cell display value will be `13`